# Draw a simplex using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, visualization

I'm trying to draw something using WPF, but it doesn't works. I'm looking something for WinForm Graphics drawing methods, and i do it like this: I have a class `Tetrahedron`, it has `Point[]` field and method `Draw`. I want to draw it on form. I'm doing it like that:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Cg1Model;

namespace Cg1Wpf
{
    internal class Tetrahedron
    {
        public readonly ShapePoint[] Points;

        public Tetrahedron(ShapePoint[] points)
        {
            if (points.Length != 4)
                throw new ArgumentException(@"Invalid points count", "points");
            Points = points;
        }

        public ImageSource Draw()
        {
            var points = Points.Select(IsometricConvertion).ToArray();

            int pixelWidth = (int) (points.Max(p => p.X) - points.Min(p => p.X));
            int pixelHeight = (int) (points.Max(p => p.Y) - points.Min(p => p.Y));

            var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 120, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                var line = new Line
                           {
                               X1 = points[i].X,
                               Y1 = points[i].Y,
                               X2 = points[i + 1].X,
                               Y2 = points[i + 1].Y,
                               SnapsToDevicePixels = true,
                               Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                               StrokeThickness = 5,
                               Fill = Brushes.Blue
                           };
                bmp.Render(line);
            }
            return bmp;
        }

        private Point IsometricConvertion(ShapePoint point)
        {
            //TODO: change to normal isometric
            var result = new Point();

            result.X = point.X;
            result.Y = point.Y;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

where ShapePoint is

```
public struct ShapePoint
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }


    public ShapePoint(int y, int x, int z) : this()
    {
        Y = y;
        X = x;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

but when i'm calling it

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShapePoint[] points =
    {
        new ShapePoint(10,20,30), 
        new ShapePoint(50,30,20),
        new ShapePoint(70,90,190),
        new ShapePoint(20,54,0)
    };
    var tetra = new Tetrahedron(points);
    Img.Source = tetra.Draw();
}
```

it doesn't draw anything. What mistake am I doing?

Comment: I see that you are drawing with black color. Any chance that your background is black too?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` - everything. Treating WPF as if it were winforms is the most common mistake. I suggest you start reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) about how to draw in WPF.

Comment: If it will be real task - i'l agree. But it's `part of term paper`, discipline `Computer graphics`. So i should do everything concerned with visualisation manualy. I should manualy write matrix for rotation not use existing, matrix for reflection and do not use existing etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is how you "draw" in WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.TetraHedron"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TetraHedron" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Polyline Points="{Binding}"
              Stroke="Black" Fill="LightGray" StrokeThickness="1"
              Stretch="Fill"/>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

public partial class TetraHedron : Window
{
    public TetraHedron()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new PointCollection
            {
                new Point(10, 20),
                new Point(50, 30),
                new Point(70, 90),
                new Point(20, 54)
            };
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

- Simple and beautiful [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to a `PointCollection`. No need for horrendous winforms-like hacks.
- Your points surely don't look like a Tetrahedron. Modify them accordingly.
- Copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.

**Side Comment:** If you're looking for drawing 3D content, WPF has [built-in support for 3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747437.aspx). You should read the documentation to get started.

Comment: I know. But i cannot use anything, except simple lines/curves. It's educational task, I can't use "Camera", i should manualy multiply matrix to do transform and so on. So question is: how can i draw it in memory and why the code above doesn't work, i get it from msdn

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky this is the `right` way to do things in WPF. If you do need to do it otherwise, Don't use WPF. your code doesn't work because your code is not written according to WPF "ways". WPF does not care what you "think" you need to do. WPF has its own ways and patterns and paradigms. It is not intended to be used as if it were winforms or any other half-baked ancient framework